# Reiniciar serviço em baixa prioridade no terceiro núcleo em C#

Tags: c#, windows

Tenho um serviço a correr na máquina em produção. Este serviço as vezes fica "parado" e a solução mais fácil é reiniciar o serviço, e ele continua a funcionar como o esperado. Há alguma maneira de eu puder buscar esse serviço num programa em `C#` e reinicia-lo? E mais, se for possível reiniciar, é possível alterar a prioridade e afinidade do serviço? Preciso que ele corra em prioridade baixa e só no terceiro núcleo do processador. Obrigado

Comment: você também pode optar pela linha de comando do windows: https://superuser.com/questions/620724/changing-windows-process-priority-via-command-line

Comment: veja: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4219923/4713574 e https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de alguma pesquisa consegui fazer o que queria. Este código pega num processo, muda a prioridade para a mais baixa, e deixa a afinidade só para o terceiro núcleo do CPU

```
     Process[] services = Process.GetProcessesByName("WindowsBusinessService");

            try
            {
                //change priority
                services[0].PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.Idle;

                //change affinity
                services[0].ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)0x0008;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("ERROR CHANGING PROCESS");
            }
```

Uma lista com os códigos para mudar de núcleos:

```
       0x1 - 0001 - Core0
       0x2 - 0010 - Core1
       0x3 - 0011 - Core1 & Core0
       0x4 - 0100 - Core2
       0x5 - 0101 - Core2 & Core0
       0x6 - 0110 - Core2 & Core1
       0x7 - 0111 - Core2 & Core1 & Core0
       0x8 - 1000 - Core3
       0x9 - 1001 - Core3 & Core0
       0xA - 1010 - Core3 & Core1
       0xB - 1011 - Core3 & Core1 & Core0
       0xC - 1100 - Core3 & Core2
       0xD - 1101 - Core3 & Core2 & Core0
       0xE - 1110 - Core3 & Core2 & Core1
       0xF - 1111 - Core3 & Core2 & Core1 & Core0
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar utilizar o namespace `System.Diagnostics` para fazer a reinicialização:

```
foreach(Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("nome do processo"))
{
    proc.Kill();
}
Process.Start(@"diretório do serviço");
```

E para alterar a prioridade do processo, use:

```
foreach(Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("nome do processo"))
{
    proc.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal;
}
```

Comment: quanto à afinidade, vi que se usar `processo.ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)1;` vou ficar com o processo a correr em 1 núcleo, mas desta forma é só o primeiro que está activado, eu preciso que seja o último. Como posso especificar isso para o `ProcessorAffinity`?

Comment: @ihavenokia Já tentou colocar 3 ao invés de 1?

Comment: claro, eu até coloquei 8 (porque aqui na minha máquina tenho mais que na máquina onde preciso do programa), pensei que o programa não fazia nada, mas depois percebi que ele seleciona o Nr de núcleos que eu colocar, e  eu precisava que o nr fosse 1, mas a posição fosse 3 (o índice deve ser 2)

Comment: @ihavenokia Tente usar isso: `proc.IdealProcessor = 3;`

Comment: não deu certo. Quando vou ao task manager ele está no núcleo [0]. E o `IdealProcessor` é um método de um Thread, não do processo. Ou será que com o tempo o programa vai passar a correr no núcleo 3?

Comment: @ihavenokia Acho que não. Realmente vou ter que admitir que não sei como lhe ajudar nessa de trocar o core.